# What are the most expensive cars you can sell to Los Santos Customs?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have gotten into the habit of stealing a car and taking it to Los Santos customs once an hour or so to sell. The prices have ranged from a lowly $1000 up to $8000 as the highest I've seen so far. What cars I should target to maximize this hourly profit? A top 5 list would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvMnvlv4JzeKdGRVQlVHVUlRY2VoZGQtaFBGYW1HVlE&usp=sharing#gid=0) community created spreadsheet, these seem to be your best options:
Gang car 13 grand you can tell them apart from others because they're green, yellow or purple and customized rims, hoods, exhuast etc.

```
Lampadi Felon GT      | $ 9 500,00
Lampadati Felon       | $ 9 000,00
Gallivanter Baller    | $ 9 000,00
Obey Rocoto           | $ 8 500,00
Ocelot F620           | $ 8 000,00
Ubermacht Oracle      | $ 8 000,00
Benefactor Dubsta     | $ 7 000,00
Albany Cavalclade     | $ 7 000,00
Ubermacht Zion        | $ 6 500,00
Ubermacht Zion Cabrio | $ 6 500,00
Benefactor Schafter   | $ 6 500,00
Ocelot Jackal         | $ 6 000,00
Benefactor Serrano    | $ 6 000,00
Ubermacht Sentinel XS | $ 6 000,00
Ubermacht Sentinel    | $ 6 000,00
Dundreary Landstalker | $ 5 800,00
Fathom FQ 2           | $ 5 000,00
Mammoth Patriot       | $ 5 000,00
```

taken from : http://ct.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV/comments/1nn7xr/gtao_los_santos_customs_car_sell_price_spreadsheet/

Comment: Can you sell them all when you are at a low level?

Comment: @xBeats_GhoStZz Yep, level should not matter if you can find the cars.

Comment: @kalina I am not sure the Felon GT is actually $22k, if you are referring to the one from one of Martin's missions, I think that is a special case where the car is modded and worth <$50k so you can still sell it.  If you just find one on the street it should still be $9.5k.  Haven't tested for sure myself though.

Comment: I merely accepted somebody elses' suggested edit and put it into the correct format, feel free to amend it as required. Refer to the edit history for more information.

Comment: @kalina ah okay, I rolled it back.

Comment: Go onto Los Santos Customs on your phone. Cars there are your options to sell, and their prices. Create another character, and you can then sell 2 an hour(may be 48minutes to a day in GTA.